# How to get text with RTF format from Rich Edit Win API?

Tags: winapi, rtf, richedit

(Sorry for my crazy English)
I want to get all the text in Rich Edit with RTF format, not plain text to a variable. I tried SendMessage() with EM_STREAMOUT to write directly Rich Edit to file, but I can't save the content to specific variables, for example LPWSTR. Please remember, only Win API, not MFC. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass your variable to the `EM_STREAMOUT` callback so it can be updated as needed, eg:

```
DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    std::stringstream *rtf = (std::stringstream*) dwCookie;
    rtf->write((char*)pbBuff, cb);
    *pcb = cb;
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
std::stringstream rtf;

EDITSTREAM es = {0};
es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR) &rtf;
es.pfnCallback = &EditStreamOutCallback; 
SendMessage(hRichEditWnd, EM_STREAMOUT, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);

// use rtf.str() as needed...
```

**Update:** to load RTF data into the RichEdit control, use `EM_STREAMIN`, eg:

```
DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamInCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    std::stringstream *rtf = (std::stringstream*) dwCookie;
    *pcb = rtf->readsome((char*)pbBuff, cb);
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
std::stringstream rtf("...");

EDITSTREAM es = {0};
es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR) &rtf;
es.pfnCallback = &EditStreamInCallback; 
SendMessage(hRichEditWnd, EM_STREAMIN, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your support!

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau! So, about insert rtf back into Rich Edit?

Comment: +1 good work. Wouldn't all this (in and out) be easier with `std::stringstream`?

Comment: Thanks @Remy! I declare 'rtf' variable as global. After read from RichEdit, now use 'rtf' to load into RichEdit, I used Breakpoint to check value of 'pbBuff':

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 System;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 

while 'rtf' is:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 System;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 Hello World\b\f1\fs20\par}

Why?

Comment: The callback may be called multiple times to stream the entire RTF. The larger the RTF, the more times the callback is likely to be called.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `EM_STREAMOUT` message is the answer.

Here is the simplest example that I can construct to demonstrate. This will save the contents of a rich edit control to a file.

```
DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    HANDLE hFile = (HANDLE)dwCookie;
    DWORD NumberOfBytesWritten;
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, pbBuff, cb, &NumberOfBytesWritten, NULL))
    {
        //handle errors
        return 1;
        // or perhaps return GetLastError();
    }
    *pcb = NumberOfBytesWritten;
    return 0;
}

void SaveRichTextToFile(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR filename)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //handle errors
    }
    EDITSTREAM es = { 0 };
    es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR) hFile;
    es.pfnCallback = EditStreamOutCallback; 
    SendMessage(hWnd, EM_STREAMOUT, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    if (es.dwError != 0)
    {
        //handle errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David! But I need store to a variable.Anyway, thankyou again!

Comment: It was not at all clear what you wanted. I thought you didn't know how to use EM_STREAMOUT at all. I also assumed you were coding in C.

Comment: You are right, David :D. I am new to Win API.
By the way, can you help me to edit Remy's code above, how to insert [std::string rtf]'s value into Rich Edit?
I understand that I need assign 'rtf' to 'pbBuff', right? But I don't know how?
I am coding Win32 application, using Visual Studio 2008.
Thanks!

Comment: I could do that. But so could Remy.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it myself first, and waiting for Remy :D

Comment: Late answer, but for future reference, wee bug above;  
    es.dwCookie = (DWORD) &hFile;  
should be  
    es.dwCookie = (DWORD) hFile;